# how to find coordinates after using Houghlinep function in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, houghlinesp

Hi guys i'm new to OpenCV.
I'm using opencv to remove lines and get removed coordinates from image.
I'm using  HoughlineP like this

```
Mat src = imread("F:/003-00.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

Mat bw;
blur(src, bw, Size(3, 3));
pyrDown(bw, bw);

//threshold(bw, bw, 170, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
Canny(bw, bw, 100, 200, 3);


Mat color_dst = Mat::zeros(bw.size(), CV_8UC1);
vector<Vec4i> lines;

HoughLinesP(bw, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 400, 300, 20);
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{

    line(color_dst, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
        Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3);

}


imwrite("F:/result.jpg", color_dst);
```

and i got a result image  like this
[HoughlinesP Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ609.jpg)

but one line actually contains many of child lines and group to one bold line 
Now I want to erode,group, and normally it to one line with two Point begin , end for every line

Here is input image 
[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swC00.jpg)

Comment: U just want to remove these lines from the actual image. Can you further clarify.

Comment: Give me the actual image I will solve it here

Comment: [sample input images](http://imgur.com/a/egGxa) Anubhav Rohatgi thanks you very much!

Comment: so do you want only the lines to be removed from the image or do you want the vector of lines?

Comment: If you draw the lines as white on top of the image instead of a new black image, it will draw white over the black lines. But the black image with lines can tell you where the pixels were removed from---just check the indices of each white pixel in the black/white line image.